# Getting an empty values when iterating json object to struct. Swift

Tags: swift, for-loop, foreach, alamofire, swifty-json

What I'm doing its sorting data from JSON response.

Here is my struct

```
struct InboundID {

let price: Double
let deepLinkURL: String
let carrier: String
let carrierImage: String
let inboundCode: String
let stringPrice: String
```

From server response i'm getting this 2 different arrays with same values that i need to find and replace from 2nd to 1st if it has matched value.

That how i'm getting values:

```
legs.forEach({ (leg) 
    let legID = leg["Id"].stringValue
    var searchInboundItinerariy: JSON = JSON.null
    var searchOutboundItinerariy: JSON = JSON.null


    for itinerariyValue in itinerariy {
      let inboundID = itinerariyValue["InboundLegId"].stringValue
      let outboundID = itinerariyValue["OutboundLegId"].stringValue

         if inboundID == legID  {
             searchInboundItinerariy = itinerariyValue
         }

         if outboundID == legID {
             searchOutboundItinerariy = itinerariyValue
         }

      let inboundPrice = searchInboundItinerariy["PricingOptions"][0]["Price"].doubleValue
      let finalInbound = InboundID(price: inboundPrice, deepLinkURL: inboundDeeplink, carrier: inboundCarrierName, carrierImage: inboundCarrierImage, inboundCode: inboundAirportCode, stringPrice: sPrice)
```

I think it happens because not all iterating values are == inboundID

output look:

[finalBound print()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7ads.jpg)

Comment: Are you using a swift JSON library like SwiftyJSON?

Comment: Yes i am using swiftyJSON